# Spring MVC Resources Not Working

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, resources

I've looked through other answer already but still having trouble. 
Here's my context file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.tehras.web.controllers"></context:component-scan>
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
</beans>
```

and Here's my JSP:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Paul Laros">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <title>Von - Minimalist Blog Theme</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro%3A400%2C400italic%2C700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Loading bar -->
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/pace.min.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shiv for IE8 support -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Please Help!

My folder structure is that resources folder is in the same directory as my servlet file.

I can post more information if needed, but i've read through many suggestions already, but I cannot see what's wrong with this! 
Thanks!

UPDATE: Here's my web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Taras's Blog</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>blog</display-name>
        <servlet-name>blog</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>blog</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Please add your web.xml

Comment: Can not find anything wrong with web.xml, can you specify project/war directory structure?

Comment: I had my resources folder in the wrong directory :(. Stupid mistake, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

Had my resources folder in the wrong folder here, if you're also having problems check that, and if that's correct then you can use the web.xml and the context.xml above as they are valid.